# Azure App Service (Web App) PCI Compliance

Tags: azure, pci-compliance

Having a hard time finding a definitive answer regarding Azure App Services (Web App) and PCI Compliance.  PCI Standards 3.1 require that TLS 1.0 be disabled as well as well as block cipher algorithms with block size of 64 bits such as DES and 3DES.  Apparently Azure Web Apps is compliant with PCI Standards 3.0 but, not with 3.1.  Is there any official position from Microsoft as to when they will meet the updated standards (3.1)? for the Web Apps service?  I have been advised that i could use an App Service Environment so as to have the ability to disable TLS 1.0 and outdated ciphers but that (of course) is a premium service and cost more money.  We have client sites that we are hosting in Azure which are failing their PCI Compliance scans due to the above issues.  Is my only solution to move my client sites to an App Service Environment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a compliance question, not a programming question.

Comment: You can find all compliance-related content at the Microsoft Trust Center, [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/). As to why a given compliance level? There's no way to answer that. Compliance procedures take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Starting April 30, 2018, you'll be able to manage what TLS versions your app service will accept.

I can't find a source to link to, but I did receive an email that included the following:

> By April 30, 2018:
>
> - Through the Azure portal and Azure Resource Manager templates, you’ll be able to select the minimum-required TLS version (1.1 or 1.2)
>     for your app.
> - We’ll configure App Service apps to require only newer TLS versions (1.1 and 1.2)—two months before the required date.
>
> After June 30, 2018:
>
> - All newly created App Service apps will be automatically configured to require TLS 1.2. You’ll still retain the option to configure
>     earlier TLS versions for your apps, if necessary, for compatibility
>     with older browser clients.

In regards to your question about removing DES and 3DES from the cipher suite, that was scheduled for March 2017 (https://appsvcssl.trafficmanager.net/) and my testing shows that it has been removed (at least from a new web app created in US East).

Comment: Yes........I saw that article.  So, if I want my client sites to pass their PCI Compliance scans, it appears my only option is to move them to an App Service Environment, correct?  I must say, this is a bit frustrating!  Microsoft states that their Web App platform is PCI Compliant but, that is not true (at least as regards the most current standards).  If I want to pass the current standards, I am forces to pay extra for the App Service Environment.

Comment: I think that's the only option to get PCI compliance "out of the box", but I've added a bit of C# code to my answer that should disable TLS1.0 and SSL3 at the application layer which may help if that's the only difference between PCI 3.0 and PCI 3.1

Comment: PCI 3.1 also requires that DES and 3DES be disabled.  Can we control those settings via .Net also?  If not, it appears we will have to go the App Service Environment option.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: It looks like DES is already disabled, but 3DES won't be disabled until March 2017, and I don't know of any way to disable 3DES via .Net (it's a controlled by a registry setting). Looks like you are going to need to move to App Service Environments.

Comment: @JeremyHutchinson I've read the same thing (March 2017), although it is now June 2017 and the latest test from Qualys on our target site reports 3DES is still enabled.

Have you heard any updates as to when it may be happening?

Comment: Weird, I seem to have forgotten what year it was for a minute there. Yes, it looks like 3DES should have already been disabled according to this site https://appsvcssl.trafficmanager.net/

I just created a new web app and tested with SSLLabs and 3DES isn't in the list. Maybe you could contact support and see why it's still available on your instance and when it will be removed?

Comment: You can submit an exception to your scan provider for TLS and show that you plan to have it disabled by the time PCI requires (which is not until 2018).  Upon doing so, you will pass your scans.

Comment: I believe there is now an option under Web Apps > Security Settings. The is a "Minimum TLS Version" at the top where you can enable/disable the appropriate version.